# Validating Spring Soap Webservice Response Serverside

Tags: web-services, spring, validation, soap, response

I'd like to validate the response of a Soap Spring Webservice against XSD on server side.
The validation result should not lead to a soap fault. 
For client compatiblity reason the webservice response contains 
the validation error e.g. like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <ns:eltResponse>
      <errCode>the error code</errorCode>
      <errMessage>the error message</errMessage>
   </ns:eltResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

I tried it with the [PayloadValidatingInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/PayloadValidatingInterceptor.html) and a custom [ValidationErrorHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/xml/validation/ValidationErrorHandler.html). 
But this lead to soap faults. Is it possible to create a response like above mentioned, e.g. with an exception resolver?